# Who first used two lambdas to typeset the wavelengths of a spectra line doublet?

Tags: spectra, notation

Also what is the accepted or most common way to typeset the wavelengths of a doublet? e.g. lambdalambda-3727,3729 with or without a hyphen? and without the Angstrom symbol?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is better suited to HSM.SE  ( https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions )

Comment: @CarlWitthoft "better suited" is simply not a close reason. Off-topic would be a close reason. A polite suggestion to the OP to consider moving it would be the proper way to respond to a better suited situation. It's only been a few hours, why not give it a day or two and see if someone here knows the answer?

Comment: @uhoh, ok ,  ` sed   s//bettersuited//belongs on // `

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I think this post matches the HSM really better. The problem is that the SE has essentially a "barbed wire" between its sites, probably nobody knows really, why. Simply closing the first post of the new user likely results that this user will be permanently lost, and it is not known yet, how will he improve. I don't know, what to do.